# Why doesn't postgresql complain when I try to order by the tablename if there is no column with that name?

Tags: postgresql

If I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE
    abc
    (
        xyz INTEGER,
        abc INTEGER
    );
```

and I do:

```
select * from abc order by abc;
```

it works and sorts by the column named abc.

However, if I **don't** have a column named 'abc':

```
CREATE TABLE
    abc
    (
        xyz INTEGER,
        abcxyz INTEGER
    );
```

but I run the same query:

```
select * from abc order by abc;
```

there is no error message returned from postgres.

I'm just wondering why postgres doesn't return an error message because clearly, 'abc' is not a valid column so I can't possibly order by that column.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.7

Comment: run `select abc from abc` and pay close attention to the output (as compared to `select *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgresql creates a default `TYPE` with the structure when we create a table. So when we use it in the query, it is returned as a `TYPE`, To verify this,

Insert a row into the table and run this

```
select pg_typeof(abc) from abc;
```

It gives the result.

```
pg_typeof
abc
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful and interesting... so, to clarify, it seems as if the name of the table becomes a pseudo-column that you can select and order by, as in: select xyz, abcxyz, abc from abc